# Netflix -- How to Stream in Different Language?

Tags: netflix, localization

There are lots of DVDs that have foreign language audio on the disc (ie foreign films might have English audio).  Is it possible to stream a movie on Instant Play with an alternate language?  Or do they only support native languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that they only support native languages. As far as I have been able to tell there is no alternate audio stream associated with the streaming videos.